# MySQL Max Connections error: User already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

Tags: mysql

I am working on a school project involving a MySQL database.  We have encountered a problem where when we try to connect to our server we get the following error:

```
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [FrienDB-Server]
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: User nwong already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
```

We are using our schools SQL server so we do not have access to changing the amount of max connections.  I have tried killing connections on MySQL Workbench but that does not work. How can we fix this?

Here is my DatabaseConnection class

```
package friendb.server.util;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.PersistenceUnitProperties;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 * Utility class for database connections.
 * @author Evan Guby
 */
public final class DatabaseConnection
{

    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "FrienDB";

    private static Map PROPERTIES = new HashMap();
    private static final String USERNAME = "nwong";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "108857304";

    /**
     * Creates and returns an entity manager connected to the persistence unit.
     * @return 
     */
    public static EntityManager getEntityManager()
    {
        PROPERTIES.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_USER, USERNAME);
        PROPERTIES.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_PASSWORD, PASSWORD);
        EntityManagerFactory emf =
                Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, PROPERTIES);

        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

In the rare occasions where it does run when I try to access something from the database through the server from our client I get this error:

```
Caused by: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: javax.resource.spi.LocalTransactionException: Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,575,262 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
```

Comment: could you show us java code fragment if it is java program

Comment: it is java i editted in my database connection class I'm not sure what other code would be helpful

Comment: We were able to connect earlier but it stopped working recently

Comment: See if [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47160/38214) is of any help.